# Launcher and Main Activity (in Java Swing application)

Tags: java, swing

Probably this is a very basic question, but here is the MWE.
I would like to launch some basic setup activity (dialog etc)
at the start of my Swing application -- this can be e.g.
database connection info so that the code is portable across
machines, etc -- and only then boot the actual application.
The example below shows this scenario: it asks what is "2+2",
and the upon submitting the answer starts up another `JFrame`.

How to make it so the "Launcher" activity disappears having launched the main activity?

Prior to posting the MWE, I have tried to have a `CardLayout` so that the launcher activity is one of the "faces",
which gets replaced by the actual activity (using e.g. `CardLayout`'s `first` and `last` methods), but there were problems with the layout not respecting my `GridBagLayout` setup (which works fine if put inside a `JFrame` of its own, but that's another story).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Launcher extends JFrame {

    private static class MainActivity extends JFrame {
        MainActivity() {
            this.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Welcome to main activity"));
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }

    JTextArea textArea;
    JButton button;

    Launcher() {
        textArea= new JTextArea("(2+2) mod 2= ?");
        button= new JButton("submit");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                String ans= textArea.getText();
                if ( ans.equals("0") ) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            JFrame frame= new MainActivity();
                            frame.pack();
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c= new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx= 0;
        c.gridy= 0;
        this.getContentPane().add(textArea,c);
        c.gridy= 1;
        this.getContentPane().add(button,c);
    }

    public static void main( String ... args ) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame= new Launcher();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

To:

```
frame.setVisible(true); 
Launcher.this.setVisible(false); // set the current window invisible!
```